# ID part: Motorola UX0160 9403

Tags: identification

Can anyone help identify this part? I've tried googling the numbers in various combinations and found nothing. This is something I bought a long time ago, recently found, and can't remember what it was for. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show the underside ... if the two metal blocks are separate, then it may be a current sensor or a switch

Comment: added top and bottom photos

Comment: my guess is that it is very low value resistor for measuring current ... the module measures the voltage drop across the metal block

Comment: The number: UX0160 looks like a custom part number, it's blue so maybe it's a Tektronix part from the 90's? I am just guessing here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case style, and pin-out suggest an old Motorola RF power amplifier. Frequency and power out and DC power-in unknown:
[image]

Comment: That definitely looks like it, yes! Thank you. Where did you find the diagram?

Comment: Found in data book (once upon a time they were paper-printed) published by Motorola: "**Motorola RF Device Data**" document DL110/D Rev 5, 1994. The part # UX0160 looks nothing like devices shown in this data book. Could be a "house #" or a special device as @Dan1138 suggests. Most devices in that data book having that style were wideband CATV VHF/UHF linear Class A amplifiers.

Comment: Well that's all consistent with what little I know about it. I found this in my shop, in a small padded envelope addressed to me, clearly something I ordered, probably bought off eBay since the return address was a private individual, and about that time I was interested in building RF amplifiers for HAM radio.